# Pipe with MomentJS not returning correct difference of time

Tags: angular, ionic3, momentjs

I built a Pipe in Ionic(Angular) that does the work of transforming the time into 'moments from now'.

This is where I'm using:

```
 dateOfEvent = '2018-02-05 19:45:40';

 <p>{{dateOfEvent | timeago}}</p>
```

> expected output: 40 minutes ago
>
> returned output: 2 hours ago

This is my Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
moment.locale('pt-br');

@Pipe({
  name: 'timeago',
})
export class TimeagoPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value) {

      let timeAgo = moment(value).fromNow();
      return timeAgo;


  }
}
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: works fine for me! Can you see a constant pattern in the results? (e.g. the actual output is always 80 minutes before the expected one)

Comment: Yes @mok, the actual output is always 2 hours before. I've set my locale to br and it looks like it's using a different locale to compare. Can you help me fix?

Answer (score 1):

Just made a fix for this. I don't know if it's the best approach but if someone has a better one just post here and I change the best answer.

All I did was to format the `dateOfEvent` to a moment value.

Then I get the `timeAgo` based on the formatted value, not the one coming from the db directly(the one from my db was being generated by moment too but someway it was not recognizing as moment when retrieving from db)

So the corrected pipe is:

```
transform(value) {

      let formatted = moment().format(value);
      let timeAgo = moment(formatted).fromNow();

      return timeAgo;

}
```

Thanks for the help!